# Sharepoint Outgoing Mail returns false

Tags: sharepoint-server, email, central-administration

Sharepoint 2016, Outgoing Email: TLS set to No. on CA and SMTP.

> Failed attempt 1 sending mail to recipients: sharepoint@thepfs.biz.
>   Mail Subject: Test subject Sharepoint. Error: SmtpException while
>   sending email: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Server does not support
>   secure connections.     at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint
>   servicePoint)     at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()     at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Email.SPSmtpClient.SendOnce(MailMessage msg,
>   Boolean useAlternateServer)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Email.SPSmtpClient.Send(MailMessage msg)